# xml appears white when textview centred

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

For some strange reason, when I centre the Hint of my EditText using gravity centre, the view of my XML turns white as shown:

[image]

But when I unclick centre, the colour goes back to normal, if anyone can point me in the right direction on how to fix this, I would appreciate it. When I run the app, the colour appears as normal (if I use gravity centre).

[image]

XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/facebookBlue"
tools:context="com.test.practise.TeamActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Bournemouth University"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="65dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="105dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="129dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Team Mode"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="128dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="169dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/et_team"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_team"
    android:layout_width="232dp"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Team Name"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:singleLine="true"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="78dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="258dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_submit_team"
    android:layout_width="239dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/et_team"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_team"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/et_team"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/et_team"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_team"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:elevation="23dp"
    android:text="OK, go!"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="75dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="325dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
    android:text="Admin? Click Here"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="39dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="475dp" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_submit_team"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your java file try this;

```
 et_team.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

also  `android:singleLine="true"` is deprectaed so use `maxLines` instead

Comment: Yeah I've tried to change the background colour of the EditText with what you suggested but it changes it to blue, however I want the EditText to be white. Whenever I choose white for the EditText it behaves as mentioned.

Comment: Still the same unfortunately

Comment: @Displayname try again... changed answer to set gravity in java file instead of in xml

Comment: i tried it on a tablet (with no java apart from the line i told you to put in)  and it worked fine so im guessing there is something else in your java file that is causing the problem! Sorry i couldn't be of any help

Comment: Ah, tried running it on the emulator and it works but in the XML its still off to the left, hence the confusion! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using this :/         `android:background="@android:color/background_light"`

Comment: I've tried changing the background of the EditText as per A. Turners answer but it either changes to blue or behaves as mentioned. I am looking for the background of the app to remain blue and the EditText to be white.